# I want to get the field name of class in android

Tags: java, android, reflection

I want to get the field name of class in android. for this I am using this code

```
public static String checkForNull(Object obj) {
    Class cls = obj.getClass();
    Field fields[] = cls.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Object object = null;
        try {
            object = field.get(obj);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            return "The field " + field.getName() + " of " + cls.getSimpleName() + " is not accessible!";
        }
        if (object == null) {
            return "The field " + field.getName() + " of " + cls.getSimpleName() + " is null!";
        } else if (object instanceof String) {
            String string = (String) object;
            if (string.equals("")) {
                return "The field " + field.getName() + " of " + cls.getSimpleName() + " is empty!";
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

but this code return generic name of class field like a,b,c...etc. This code work fine in netbeans.

Comment: Class is very simple only some public fields and when I run on java netbeans it shows real name but in android studio it show a for first field name and b for second field name and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like obfuscated names, most probably you have default settings for ProGuard and Android SDK performs some code obfuscation, see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

If you would like to see original field names, you should disable obfuscation either completely or for this particular class / package.

Comment: Can help me how can I disable obfuscated. I have tried by adding -dontobfuscate in proguard-rules.pro file but no success

Comment: To disable obfuscation, as article describes, you should modify "build.gradle" file and set "minifyEnabled false" and/or "useProguard false". I would suggest to set both to `false`

Comment: Also look at "keep" options: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code either through "proguard-android.txt" file or via `@Keep` annotation on the class you do not what to be obfuscated